# Convert Spark DataFrame schema to new schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have multiple spark jobs which reading from different sources, they have different schema but they are very close, what I want to do is to write all of them to the same Redshift table so for that I need to unify all the DataFrame schema, what is the best way to do it?

let's say schema for the first input data is like:

```
  val schema1 = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("date", DateType),
    StructField("campaign_id", StringType),
    StructField("campaign_name", StringType),
    StructField("platform", StringType),
    StructField("country", StringType),
    StructField("views", DoubleType),
    StructField("installs", DoubleType),
    StructField("spend", DoubleType)
  ))
```

And Schema of seconf inout source is like:

```
  val schema2 = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("date", DateType),
    StructField("creator_id", StringType),
    StructField("creator_name", StringType),
    StructField("platform", StringType),
    StructField("views", DoubleType),
    StructField("installs", DoubleType),
    StructField("spend", DoubleType),
    StructField("ecpm", DoubleType)
  ))
```

The Table Schema (expected Unify DataFrame):

```
  val finalSchema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("date", DateType),
    StructField("account_name", StringType),
    StructField("adset_id", StringType),
    StructField("adset_name", StringType),
    StructField("campaign_id", StringType),
    StructField("campaign_name", StringType),
    StructField("pub_id", StringType),
    StructField("pub_name", StringType),
    StructField("creative_id", StringType),
    StructField("creative_name", StringType),
    StructField("platform", StringType),
    StructField("install_source", StringType),
    StructField("views", IntegerType),
    StructField("clicks", IntegerType),
    StructField("installs", IntegerType),
    StructField("cost", DoubleType)
  ))
```

As you can see in the final schema I have some columns that might not be in the input schema so it should be null, some columns name also should get renamed. And some of the columns like `ecpm` should get dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Add `index` `columns` to both the `dataframes` and `join` them based on `index` so there will be one-to-one mapping. After that `select` only your desired `columns` from `joined` `dataframe`.

1. If you have two `dataframes` like below

   ```
   // df1.show
   +-----+---+
   | name|age|
   +-----+---+
   |Alice| 25|
   |  Bob| 29|
   |  Tom| 26|
   +-----+---+

   //df2.show
   +--------+-------+
   |    city|country|
   +--------+-------+
   |   Delhi|  India|
   |New York|    USA|
   |  London|     UK|
   +--------+-------+
   ```
2. Now add `index` `columns` and get one-to-one mapping

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

   val df1Index=df1.withColumn("index1",monotonicallyIncreasingId)

   val df2Index=df2.withColumn("index2",monotonicallyIncreasingId)

   val joinedDf=df1Index.join(df2Index,df1Index("index1")===df2Index("index2"))

   //joinedDf

   +-----+---+------+--------+-------+------+
   | name|age|index1|    city|country|index2|
   +-----+---+------+--------+-------+------+
   |Alice| 25|     0|   Delhi|  India|     0|
   |  Bob| 29|     1|New York|    USA|     1|
   |  Tom| 26|     2|  London|     UK|     2|
   +-----+---+------+--------+-------+------+
   ```

Now you can write you query like below

```
val queryList=List(col("name"),col("age"),col("country"))
joinedDf.select(queryList:_*).show

//Output df
+-----+---+-------+
| name|age|country|
+-----+---+-------+
|Alice| 25|  India|
|  Bob| 29|    USA|
|  Tom| 26|     UK|
+-----+---+-------+
```

Comment: How do you know they are related?

Comment: @thebluephantom He didn't provide data but he need to implement a join to combine data from two dataframes. I did one to one mapping. He can also apply join on common column like date etc.

Comment: They are separate jobs I cannot join the DataFrames, each job has its own schema but should write unified version into DB

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a fully automatic way of achieving this. If your schema is fixed and not particularly complex you may manually adjust schema and `union` the results.

For the sake of argument let's say you want to include columns `col1` and `col2` from `frame1` and include `col2` and `col4` of `frame2`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val subset1 = frame1.select($"col1", $"col2", lit(null).as("col4"))
val subset2 = frame2.select(lit(null).as("col1"), $"col2", $"col4")
val result = subset1 union subset2
```

achieves just that. We specify each column manually so we can skip any columns we like.

Comment: your approach is what I am doing right now, but I was hoping to find a better approach.